# CSS3 Rounded Corner white background

Tags: css, button

I have this button that appears fine on desktop and mobile, but when viewed on an android tablet there is this white background around the corners where the transparency for the button would be. Has anyone encountered this?

```
button.css3button {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: none;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#41f0ed 0%,#278a88);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#41f0ed), to(#278a88));
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow:
    0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
    inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
    0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
    inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow:
    0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
    inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    text-shadow:
    0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.2),
    0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

Comment: Does it happen if you remove the `box-shadow` or the `gradient`?

Comment: Yes, but I then took off the webkit-box-shadow, and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks for your answer. The only thing now is that I'm not getting my shadow effects for the two devices. Desktop is still fine with Chrome, but Safari it's lost it's shadow style as well.

Comment: I added that as an answer. You may be stuck with not having the shadow on Android tablets.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
background:none;
```

to

```
background: transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `box-shadow` or `gradient`. I imagine one of them is the culprit. If it is, you can do a conditional check for and Android tablet, and exclude that from your CSS.

```js
var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if ( /android/.test( userAgent ) && !/mobile/.test( userAgent ) ) {

    //it's an android tablet, remove box-shadow 

};
```